# Integrating Poisson Equation over two different regions knowing only two boundary conditions for the potentials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

Poisson Equation for electric potential is: 
$$\nabla^2 V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$
Solving the equation require two boundary condition. I'm confused about the use of these boundary conditions in some situations, like for example the following.

---

Consider two conductor planes, both at zero potential ($V=0$). Between the plates, there is a region with a charge density $\rho$ (the grey one) and another one with no charge.
[image]

Suppose that I need to solve Poisson Equation in order to find out the electric potential in all the region.
The problem is about the boundary conditions: what are the boundary conditions in this case?

Surely I have that $V(0)=0$ and $V(2d)=0$ but this is not enough since I need to split potential in two and integrate the equation in the two different regions.
$$\begin{cases} V(0<x<d)=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon} x^2+c_1 x+c_2 \\ V(d<x<2d)=c_3x+c_4 \end{cases}$$

Another condition to impose could be that the potential must be continous in $x=d$. The three conditions gives
 $$\begin{cases} c_2=0 \\ c_4=-2d \,c_3\\c_1+c_3=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}d \end{cases}$$

But I need one more condition in order to solve the equation, and I do not see where to get it.

---

In general, if Poisson Equation has to be solved over two different regions, how can I manage with situations like this one where I have only two potentials known but one of the potential $V(d)$ is "in common" between the two regions but it is not known in principle?

Comment: You already tried with the derivative of $V$? remember it is discontinuous when there is net charge in the interface between regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing relation is the continuity of electric displacement at $x=d$ which, due to the same $\epsilon$, is the continuity of electric field, i.e., the continuity of the derivatives of the potentials $V_{left}$ and $V_{right}$ at $x=d$. This yields $$\frac{\partial V_{left}}{\partial x}|_{x=d}=\frac{\partial V_{right}}{\partial x}|_{x=d}$$ which gives for your constants the missing 4th equation $$-2\frac{\rho}{\epsilon} d+c_1= c_3$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, since there is a charge distribution for $0<x<d$ shouldn't $E=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$ be discontinous in $x=d$?

Comment: @Soren - no, for constant $\epsilon$ the electric field should be continuous  also when a space charge is present as long as you don't have a surface charge (areal charge $\eta$) concentrated at $x=d$, which would cause a discontinuity $\epsilon (E_{right}-E_{left}) =\eta$. But this is obviously not the case.

Comment: Thanks again! By "constant $\epsilon$" do you mean that $\epsilon$ has the same value both for $0<x<d$ and $d<x<2d$ or that $\epsilon $ is a constant for $0<x<d$ but it can be different for $d<x<2d$? And if in $0<x<d$ there is a charged **dielectric** with constant $\epsilon$  and for $d<x<2d$ there is vacuum with constant $\epsilon_0$, and $\epsilon \neq \epsilon_0$, the electric field would be discontinous in $x=d$?

Comment: @Soren - The electric field continuity holds when $\epsilon$ is the same everywhere. In general, you have a continuity of electric displacement $\epsilon E$. If you have a charged dielectric with absolute permittivity $\epsilon$ left and vacuum with $\epsilon_0$ right, this would give you at $x=d$ the condition $\epsilon E_{left}=\epsilon_0 E_{right}$ .